# Using Telescope fuzzy finder to find files in nested git repositories

Tags: git, neovim, telescope.nvim

I am working on an embedded C project using neovim that pulls in git repositories as part of the project structure. The fuzzy finder functionality of telescope seems to not like to enter any folders that happen to be standalone git repositories. Is there any way to get telescope to look in those repositories for files?

```
vim.keymap.set('n', '<leader>ff', builtin.find_files, {})
```

the keymap pulls up the fuzzy finder, as expected, but it will not look through the folders that happen to be git repositories of their own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it search them when you cd into the nested directories, and run the finder there? Are the git repositories symbolic links?

It might also be due to .gitignore settings.

`:help telescope.builtin.find_files()` will show you how you can adjust symbolic links or gitignore settings.